# Arduino pin descriptions

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, lcd, pins, keypad

[image]

Hello, actually I am very new in electronics. Im using this as a reference in connecting lcd and 4x4 keypad in my my controller ( an arduino clone) Gizduino ATMEGA644 but I'm having a problem because of its pin different pin description.

[image]

When I tried connecting it the same with my reference (without looking at the pin description)I'm only having black box in the lcd after uploading a sample program. can someone help me?

this is the connection I used:

[image]

Comment: Is this a follow-on to your [previous question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/95897/2191) or are you using a different LCD this time?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Actually im using a different lcd this time. Im using an lcd like on my reference.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I am using standard lcd and 4x4 keypad connected to my microcontroller via breadboard GPIO pins

Answer (score 2):

Where the sketch initialises the LiquidCrystal library, substitute the pin numbers you are actually using

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(13,12,11,10,9,8); // RS, Enable, D4,D5,D6,D7
```

The Arduino Uno in your Fritzing diagram has the following pinout

[image]

You GizDuino+ has

[image]

The usual LCD pinout is

[image]

So you are possibly using pins 8-13 instead of 0-5 (4 x data, enable, rs)

If you installed the gizDuino cores in the Arduino IDE, you should be using 8-13, the compiler will produce the correct code

Comment: So I need to connect the yellow wires to pins 8-13 of my gizduino ?

Comment: @New: you can connect them to almost any pins (that are not already in use), Just put those pin numbers into the `LiquidCrystal lcd(...);` statement (in the right order). See the [Manual](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalConstructor)

Comment: so I need to change this code LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2); to which ever pin i used?

Comment: @New: That is right.

Comment: I did change the codes into this LiquidCrystal lcd(15, 14, 13,12, 11, 8);  but still i got no output but black boxes .

Comment: I'd try adjusting the contrast, then edit the Q to add a photo of the wiring that is clear enough to see what LCD pins are connected to what GizDuino pins.

Comment: I tried adjusting the contrast but it doesnt work. I'll and a photo of my wiring in just a bit

Comment: I included how I connected the lcd to gizduino, is it wrong?

Comment: That's (15,14,13,12,9,8) not (15,14,13,12,11,8) as in your earlier comment

Comment: Ow, my mistake, but still the output is black boxes